# Parsing a Hexadecimal String to an Integer throws a NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, integer, parseint, hex

So, In Java, you know how you can declare integers like this:

```
int hex = 0x00ff00;
```

I thought that you should be able to reverse that process. I have this code:

```
Integer.valueOf(primary.getFullHex());
```

where primary is an object of a custom Color class. It's constructor takes an Integer for opacity (0-99) and a hex String (e.g. `00ff00`).

This is the `getFullHex` method:

```
public String getFullHex() {
    return ("0x" + hex);
}
```

When I call this method it gives my this `NumberFormatException`:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0xff0000"
```

I can't understand what's going on. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Will this help?

```
Integer.parseInt("00ff00", 16)
```

`16` means that you should interpret the string as 16-based (hexadecimal). By using `2` you can parse binary number, `8` stands for octal. `10` is default and parses decimal numbers.

In your case `Integer.parseInt(primary.getFullHex(), 16)` won't work due to `0x` prefix prepended by `getFullHex()` - get rid of and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that `Integer.parseInt(..)` could take another parameter! Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Comment: not work java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "0x920B540C", color2 = Integer.parseInt(color_2,16); (with argbA)

Comment: Even if you remove the `0x` prefix from the input string `"0x920B540C"` and parse it in base 16, hex `920B540C` is decimal `2450215948`, which is more than the max value that a 32bit signed `int` can hold (dec `2147483647`, hex `0x7FFFFFFF` - see [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)). You would have to use a 64bit signed `long` instead (Java doesn't have unsigned integer types).

Comment: I came here searching for an elegant solution for _getting rid of 0x_. So -1 for not mentionig `Integer.decode()`.

Answer (score 43):

Try to use decode method:

```
Integer.decode("0x00ff00");
```

DecodableString:

- Signopt DecimalNumeral
- Signopt 0x HexDigits
- Signopt 0X HexDigits
- Signopt # HexDigits
- Signopt 0 OctalDigits

You can read about it here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode(java.lang.String)

Comment: Best answer IMHO.

Comment: Just adding that this doesn't handle binary (`0b...`) prefixes

Answer (score 40):

Integer.valueOf(string) assumes a decimal representation. You have to specify that the number is in hex format, e.g.

```
int value = Integer.valueOf("00ff0000", 16);
```

Note that [Integer.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)(string,16); does not accept a prefix of `0x`. If your string contains the `0x` prefix, you can use [Integer.decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29)("0x00ff0000");

Comment: Hey this is working only for  00ff0000 not for 80ff0000 . I have string like String hex="803BB9FF"; and i want to covert this into int color=0x803BB9FF please help

Comment: @AshishSahu It's impossible to help when you don't describe what happens, and what you expect to happen. 0x803BB9FF is -2143569409 (since int in Java is signed). So what's "not working" about -2143569409  ?

Comment: I have 8char color string like "803BB9FF"  now i want to convert it in int value like 0x803BB9FF (int) i tryied with "003bb9ff " then it's working but not working with 80 prefix

Comment: But thanks for reply my vote+. now i got another solution : int color=Color.parseColor("#"+"803bb9ff");

Comment: `Integer.decode` was exactly what I needed! - it's basically parseInt but handles more variety of input formats

Comment: `0x803BB9FF` is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`0x7FFFFFFF`), that is why `Integer.parseInt()` and `Integer.decode()` can't handle it.  Use `Long` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The *parseInt* method only accepts the number part, not any kind of "base" indicator such as "0x" for hexadecimal or "0" for octal. Use it like this

```
int decimal = Integer.parseInt("1234", 10);
int octal = Integer.parseInt("1234", 8);
int hex = Integer.parseInt("1234", 16);
```

Answer (score 3):

Would this work?

```
Long.parseUnsignedLong(value, 16);
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was working with "800b6b0b": 2,148,231,947

Just over the 32 bit limit

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
String hex = "FA"; 
int intValue = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
```

And if you want to generate hex representation of an integer, use

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(12);
```