# Converting String to char when String is a valid char

Tags: java, android, string, char, android-bluetooth

I am doing socket communication using bluetooth in which I am getting hex values as a variables in string format.

I can write -

```
char char1= 0x7D;
```

But somehow if value `0x7D` is string then how to convert that to char.

For example, I can't do -

```
String string1 = "0x7D";
char char1 = (char)string1;
```

Any approach to do that ?

I want this because I can write to socket with -

```
char[] uploadCommand2 =  {0x7d, 0x4d, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xcb};
```

But can't if `0x7d` is a string like --

```
char[] uploadCommand2 =  {string1, 0x4d, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xcb};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert/parse from String to char in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853502/how-to-convert-parse-from-string-to-char-in-java)

Comment: @UrsulRosu - that would return "0" for him. Not what he wants

Comment: not a duplicate, and I don't understand why this was downvoted. That's a good question, properly asked, with enough information to try and answer it.

Comment: @njzk2 Removed close vote. That was for the question before his edit... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you strip off the `0x` prefix for your hex `String` representation, you can use `Integer.parseInt` and cast to `char`.

See **edit** below for an alternative (possibly more elegant solution).

```
String s = "0x7D";
//                  | casting to char
//                  |    | parsing integer ...
//                  |    |                | on stripped off String ...
//                  |    |                |               | with hex radix
System.out.println((char)Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2), 16));
```

**Output**

```
}
```

**Edit**

As [njzk2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671543/njzk2) points out:

```
System.out.println((char)(int)Integer.decode(s));
```

... will work as well.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11377996/671543 no need to strip the 0x, `decode` does that

Comment: @Mena - Isn't it possible without stripping 0x ? Can't I get char `0x7D` ?

Comment: @VedPrakash see my edit, after njzk2's suggestion. The `decode` method will do just that. However you'll need to double cast.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt(String)` returns an Integer representation of the given String from which you can then obtain the character.

Answer (score 0):

```
String string1 = "0x7D";
char char1 = (char) Integer.parseInt(string1.substring(2), 16);
```

Edit: This works, but `Integer.decode()` is the way to go here (thanks to njzk2).

Comment: Isn't it possible without stripping 0x ? Can't I get char `0x7D` ?

Comment: @VedPrakash: No. The documentation states that the string can only contain `+`, `-` and digits of the specified radix (in this case, `0` - `9`, `a` - `f`, `A` - `F`).