# Convert String array to int values and store it in int array

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, int

I have this part of my code:

```
int[] myIntArray = {0x2e80,0x008c,0x0993,0x09c5,0x058b,0x4c9c,0x0390,0x1e96,0x0989,0x0ac4,0x4cad,0x0d93,0x09c5,0x0a84,0x0591,0x04c5,0x058b,0x4c9c,0x0390,0x1ec5,0x0d87,0x0589,0x0591,0x0580,0x1fc4,0x4cb2,0x0591,0x048a,0x1991,0x4c84,0x4c8d,0x1988,0x0e89,0x09c5,0x0e90,0x18c5,0x1e80,0x0d96,0x038b,0x0d87,0x0080,0x4c86,0x038b,0x0a8c,0x0880,0x0286,0x09c5,0x058b,0x4c9c,0x0390,0x1ec5,0x0392,0x02c5,0x1c8a,0x1b80,0x1e96,0x4c9c,0x0390,0x4c86,0x0d8b,0x028a,0x18c5,0x0e80,0x4c96,0x1986,0x0f80,0x1f96,0x0a90,0x00c5,0x0397,0x4c8d,0x0d95,0x1c9c,0x42e5};
for (int i=0; i<=73; i++){
  String s1=Decrypt(k,myIntArray[i]);
  String s2= s1.substring(2,6);
  String s=convertHexToString(s2);
  System.out.print(s);
}
```

That takes hex values from the array and do some operations on it. And its working just fine as i want.

I want to do the same thing but i want to read the values from a file and do the same operations on it, i tried this :

```
String token1 = "";
Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new    File("chipertext.txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");
List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();
while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
  token1 = inFile1.next();
  temps.add(token1);
}
inFile1.close();
String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[74]);
int[] myIntArray = new int[tempsArray.length];

for (int i = 0; i < tempsArray.length; i++) {
  myIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempsArray[i]);
}
for (int i=0; i<=73; i++){
  String s1=Decrypt(k,myIntArray[i]);
  String s2= s1.substring(2,6);
  String s=convertHexToString(s2);
  System.out.print(s);
}
```

But i get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x2e80  0x2e80
0x008c
0x0993
0x09c5
0x058b
0x4c9c
0x0390
0x1e96
0x0989
0x0ac4
0x4cad
0x0d93
0x09c5
0x0a84
0x0591
0x04c5
0x058b
0x4c9c
0x0390
0x1ec5
0x0d87
0x0589
0x0591
0x0580"
```

the values stored in the file like this :

```
0x2e80
0x008c
0x0993
0x09c5
0x058b
0x4c9c
0x0390
0x1e96
0x0989
0x0ac4
0x4cad
0x0d93
0x09c5
0x0a84
0x0591
0x04c5
0x058b
0x4c9c
0x0390
0x1ec5
0x0d87
0x0589
0x0591
0x0580
```

I think this means that that string cant be stored as integer right? then how to do it ? and how it was stored in integer array before ?! i don't know can someone please help me?

**WORKING CODE**

```
String token1 = "";
Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("chipertext.txt"));
List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();
while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
token1 = inFile1.next();
temps.add(token1);
}
inFile1.close();
String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[73]);
int[] myIntArray = new int[tempsArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < tempsArray.length; i++) {
myIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempsArray[i].substring(2), 16);
}
for (int i=0; i<=73; i++){
   String s1=Decrypt(k,myIntArray[i]);
   String s2= s1.substring(2,6);
   String s=convertHexToString(s2);
   System.out.print(s);
}
```

Thank you all for the help !!!

Comment: Please post how is the data stored within the file you are using.

Comment: It means somewhere you're attempting to read `0x2e80 .......` as input. 

Try some debugging. Check your input file and also do a Sysout in your loop of each token to see what you're storing.

Comment: try this:

myIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempsArray[i], 16);

Comment: @Trobbins i did try to print each token and its correct!

Comment: @RaphaelMoita tried it and same error :(

Comment: How are you generating the hexadecimal numbers? Is it `toHexString`?

Comment: Reading your code, you are supposed to separate your values with commas, plus, it would help if you posted the actual error and file used

Comment: @npinti no i have them already, i didnt use any function to generate them.

Comment: @jamp this is the actual file im using and the actual error message, but i didnt post them all just because they are long

Comment: is this part of the actual error message. For input string: "0x2e80 ......." ?

Comment: @jamp should i save them in the same line but seperated by comma's in the file ? like 0x0589, 0x0591, 0x0580 ...

Comment: @jamp replace the dots with these 0x2e80
0x008c
0x0993
0x09c5
0x058b
0x4c9c
0x0390
0x1e96
0x0989
0x0ac4
0x4cad
0x0d93
0x09c5
0x0a84
0x0591
0x04c5
0x058b
0x4c9c
0x0390
0x1ec5
0x0d87
0x0589
0x0591
0x0580

Comment: @jamp i just put the dots because its long.

Comment: see.. that was an important detail... you are reading the whole file as a single number. Yes, put them in a line with commas or change the code to use a new line as delimiter

Comment: This looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377944/parsing-a-hexadecimal-string-to-an-integer-throws-a-numberformatexception

Comment: @jamp okay im sorry for that, updated. but how i write delimiter for new line?

Comment: Just look at all the answers here... they are correct... if it's not working, you are doing something else wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work providing all of your numbers are formatted the same

```
String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[74]);
int[] myIntArray = new int[tempsArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < tempsArray.length; i++) {
  myIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempsArray[i].substring(2), 16);
  System.out.println(myIntArray[i]);
}
```

If it doesn't work then print out what is going into the loop and see if you are parsing the file correctly. Print one item from your string array you got from the file you parsed and feed it into this.

```
    String hex = "0x4c9c";
    int value = Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(2), 16);
    System.out.println(value);
```

Print out the output of your file parse, most likely it wont match what you are expecting.

```
List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();
while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
  token1 = inFile1.next();
  temps.add(token1);

  System.out.println(token1); //Check this output. Is it a hex string?
}
inFile1.close();
```

Comment: tried it and i got the first hex correctly : 
11904
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2 note that i changed usDelimiter("[;\r\n+]");

Comment: String index out of range: -2 is coming from the line tempsArray[i].substring(2). Which means you are parsing your file incorrectly. Start by printing out the output System.out.print.ln(token1) and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: WORKED !! just removed the useDelimiter and it worked !! THANKS ALOT !!

Answer (score 0):

There a two possibilities for your posted code

1. you store the hex codes different in the file

   // instead of
   0x2e80
   // as
   2e80

   // and amend the code to specify the radix
   myIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempsArray[i], 16);
2. or store them as current

   // and amend the code to remove the prefix and specify the radix
   myIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempsArray[i].substring(2), 16);

see the code snippets for both solutions

for case 1.)

```
List<String> temps = new ArrayList<>();
temps.add("2e80");
String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[74]);
int parseInt = Integer.parseInt(tempsArray[0], 16);
System.out.println("parseInt = " + parseInt);
```

for case 2.)

```
List<String> temps = new ArrayList<>();
temps.add("0x2e80");
String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[74]);
int parseInt = Integer.parseInt(tempsArray[0].substring(2), 16);
System.out.println("parseInt = " + parseInt);
```

output for both snippets is

```
parseInt = 11904
```

**edit**

A fixed version of the OPs code

```
// import java.nio.charset.Charset;
// import java.nio.file.Files;
// import java.nio.file.Paths;
// import java.util.List;

List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("chipertext.txt"), 
        Charset.defaultCharset());
int[] myIntArray = new int[lines.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < myIntArray.length; i++) {
    myIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(lines.get(i).substring(2), 16);
}
```

Comment: @Lamawy: One thing that I have noticed that that you do not need this part: `.useDelimiter(",\\s*")` if you have each value in a separate line.

Comment: @Lamawy If you still the the same error you need to investigate what do you store into `tempsArray`.

Comment: @Lamawy Have a look of the added more simplified working solution.

Comment: @SubOptimal i should impory package for Path.get right ?

Comment: @Lamawy I updated my answer with all import statements needed for the snippet.

Comment: @SubOptimal tried it and i get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x"

Comment: @Lamawy If you have used the posted snipped it means you have a line `  0x` in your file. If you have not used the posted snippet, please update your question to include the code you are using and the input file which cause the NPE. Otherwise this will be a remote-guess-debugging-session.

Comment: yes i have used the posted file and it does contains 0x, but what is the problem ?

Comment: @SubOptimal i think the mistake is here useDelimiter(",\\s*") does this read line by line ?

Comment: @Lamawy In the last posted snippet there is no `useDelimiter(",\\s*")`. The snippet reads the lines using the API into a `List<String>`. If you don't want to use this approach (for what ever reason) you should update your question to provide **all** necessary information. Best would be to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @SubOptimal Worked, i updated my post. actually all of the answers are correct but there were a small mistake. REALLy THANK YOU FOR THE HELP !!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at Tomasz Nurkiewicz's answer here :  [Parsing a Hexadecimal String to an Integer throws a NumberFormatException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377944/parsing-a-hexadecimal-string-to-an-integer-throws-a-numberformatexception)

To resume you need to use

```
Integer.parseInt(tempsArray[i], 16)
```

The radix parameter sets at 16 tells parseInt to parse the String for hexa value. Prior to that, you need to delete every "0x"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are storing `0x` to denote it as hexadecimal number you can use Integer.parseInt method which accepts `radix` parameter. here radix 10 means its decimals , radix 16 means hexadecimals. and you could use the substring Method of String to remove the `0x` noise .

so solution would look like below

```
 System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("-FF", 16) ); // prints -255 

        String [] hexaDecimalNumbers = {"0x2e80","0x008c","0x0993","0x09c5","0x058b","0x4c9c","0x0390","0x1e96","0x0989","0x0ac4","0x4cad","0x0d93","0x09c5","0x0a84","0x0591","0x04c5","0x058b","0x4c9c","0x0390","0x1ec5","0x0d87","0x0589","0x0591","0x0580","0x1fc4","0x4cb2","0x0591","0x048a","0x1991","0x4c84","0x4c8d","0x1988","0x0e89","0x09c5","0x0e90","0x18c5","0x1e80","0x0d96","0x038b","0x0d87","0x0080","0x4c86","0x038b","0x0a8c","0x0880","0x0286","0x09c5","0x058b","0x4c9c","0x0390","0x1ec5","0x0392","0x02c5","0x1c8a","0x1b80","0x1e96","0x4c9c","0x0390","0x4c86","0x0d8b","0x028a","0x18c5","0x0e80","0x4c96","0x1986","0x0f80","0x1f96","0x0a90","0x00c5","0x0397","0x4c8d","0x0d95","0x1c9c","0x42e5"};
        for(String hexaDecimal: hexaDecimalNumbers) {
            System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(hexaDecimal.substring(2), 16) + " , ");
        }
```

when I will run it I prints output as below

```
11904 , 140 , 2451 , 2501 , 1419 , 19612 , 912 , 7830 , 2441 , 2756 , 19629 , 3475 , 2501 , 2692 , 1425 , 1221 , 1419 , 19612 , 912 , 7877 , 3463 , 1417 , 1425 , 1408 , 8132 , 19634 , 1425 , 1162 , 6545 , 19588 , 19597 , 6536 , 3721 , 2501 , 3728 , 6341 , 7808 , 3478 , 907 , 3463 , 128 , 19590 , 907 , 2700 , 2176 , 646 , 2501 , 1419 , 19612 , 912 , 7877 , 914 , 709 , 7306 , 7040 , 7830 , 19612 , 912 , 19590 , 3467 , 650 , 6341 , 3712 , 19606 , 6534 , 3968 , 8086 , 2704 , 197 , 919 , 19597 , 3477 , 7324 , 17125 ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Integer.parseInt(tempsArray[i]);` use `Integer.parseInt(tempsArray[i].substring(2), 16));`