# How to convert string representation of an ASCII value to character

Tags: java, string, character, ascii

I have a String containing ASCII representation of a character i.e.

```
String test = "0x07";
```

Is there a way I can somehow parse it to its character value.

I want something like

```
char c = 0x07;
```

But what the character exactly is, will be known only by reading the value in the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a Hexadecimal String to an Integer throws a NumberFormatException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377944/parsing-a-hexadecimal-string-to-an-integer-throws-a-numberformatexception)

Comment: @shmosel That answer looks good too. I just didn't find it when I was struggling with my issue because may be I wasn't searching with right keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add one step:

```
String test = "0x07";
int decimal = Integer.decode(test);
char c = (char) decimal;
```