# I have converted stringbuffer to strings but how to convert string to unicode int?

Tags: java, android, string, unicode, int

I can see emojis if I enter unicode directly and convert it to `String` with a method like:

```
int intUnicode = 0x1F601;

public String getEmojiByUnicode(int unicode) {
    return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
}
```

But I just can't wrap my head around how to convert when the unicode value is a `String` like:

```
String strUnicode = "0xf601";
```

How to covert it to an `Integer` like I did it directly. When I try to use `Integer.parseInt(strUnicode)` compiler throws an error every time.

```
InputStream is = assetManager.open("emoji_unicode.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
if (is != null){
    try {
        while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sbuffer.append(data + "\n");
            String j = sbuffer.toString().trim();
            int k = Integer.parseInt(j,16);
            String l = getEmojiByUnicode(k);
            emoArray.add(l);
        }
        btn.setText(emoArray.get(5));
        is.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It's not very hard, I know I'm very close but still it won't get to me. Any help would be very appreciated.
Regard

Comment: Your unicode string that you're starting with isn't the same as the one you generate in your first example.  You should look at the [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoding, and see how it applies to code points in [the range you're working with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+10000_to_U+10FFFF).  Your compiler is complaining because the string you're giving it isn't valid UTF-16.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a Hexadecimal String to an Integer throws a NumberFormatException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377944/parsing-a-hexadecimal-string-to-an-integer-throws-a-numberformatexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to parse a *hex* string (unicode "encodings" are hexadecimal numbers), and `Integer.parseInt()` has some odd limits for doing so. Take a look at this answer:

[Parsing a Hexadecimal String to an Integer throws a NumberFormatException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377944/parsing-a-hexadecimal-string-to-an-integer-throws-a-numberformatexception)