# NumberFormatException - with String of an Hex Value

Tags: java, exception

I got a stream of byte this stream is a bytearray ( byte[] stream ) now i want parse this byte first to an hex value, e.g. 80 = "0x50" then transform this to an int

But for some values like 0xB8 i got an `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0xB8"

How could i manage this exception? Maybe with an other type of parse or different type data?

```
byte k = stream[i];

        int b = 0;
        try {
            b = Integer.parseInt(String.format("0x%02X",k),16);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377944/parsing-a-hexadecimal-string-to-an-integer-throws-a-numberformatexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377944/parsing-a-hexadecimal-string-to-an-integer-throws-a-numberformatexception)

```
byte k = stream[i];

        int b = 0;
        try {
            String hexStringNumber = String.format("0x%02X",k);
            b = Integer.decode(hexStringNumber);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use overloaded **parseInt** method with radix.
For hex value an example:

```
Integer.parseInt("84B",16);
```

Comment: @GianlucaBenucci Check what it returns String.format("0x%02X",k), it can return a non-hex string.

Comment: You'll need to remove the leading `0x` for this to work. `Integer.parseInt("84B",16)` returns 2123, but with `0x84B` you get a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Integer.parseInt(String.format("0b%02X",k),16);
```

Binary values are written using "0bxx" syntax