# How to convert a string into hexadecimal value?

Tags: java, hex, rgb

I have 3 RGB values and I want to get the hexadecimal `int` value that represents them, combined.

For example, suppose I have `R=255, G=30, B=0`, this is `FF1E00`, how to get the equivalent `int` value?

So far I have managed to get a hexadecimal string `FF1E00` from the values, but how to get the `int` value now?

```
// User defined rgb value
int r = 255;
int g = 30;
int b = 0;
// Converts rgb to hex, but in string
String hexString = String.format("%02X%02X%02X", r, g, b);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377944/parsing-a-hexadecimal-string-to-an-integer-throws-a-numberformatexception (not exactly a duplicate, but answers contain a solution)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting A String To Hexadecimal In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java)

Comment: @Renato nope, that question is about something else.

Comment: Lookup `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)`

Comment: Your text description does not line up with the code example. You say you have a string input in hexadecimal already (but uppercase and without `0x` prefix). But your code starts with 3 RGB integer values. Voting to close because needs clarity.

Comment: @Zabuzard and ends with this: `String hexString = String.format("%02X%02X%02X", r, g, b);` which gives the format they stated in the question.

Comment: Anyway, OP, since you already have the three components you can just do `int rgb = r << 16 | g << 8 | b` without conversions.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I get 16719360                                                                                                                       from your solution.

Comment: Are you starting out from the three `int`s `r`, `g` and `b`? Or have you got a string from the outset? Sorry, your question is  not quite clear, you should edit it and clarify, please.

Comment: @SirNUB 16719360 is the same value as FF1E00. You’re done. [Try it here](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html), for example.

Comment: @SirNUB of course you do. A number is a number, it's not a hex number or a decimal number. A representation only makes sense in the context of a string.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! There is no such thing as a *hexadecimal `int`*. A Java `int` is represented in binary internally and prints in decimal when you print it. Always.

Answer (score 1):

### RGB to int (after OP clarified)

You said you would like to convert your three RGB values to an integer. The integer `ff1e00` (hexadecimal) which is `16719360` in decimal.

To do so, you can go directly from the RGB values using the following logic:

```
int hex = r << 16 | g << 8 | b;
```

---

Alternativly you can also convert your `hexString` back to an integer:

```
int hex = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);
```

---

By the way, do not expext `System.out.println(hex)` to print a hexadecimal value. It will be `16719360`, so decimal. `int` does **not** store any information about its base. Integers are unaware of a base. They only come into play once you want to visualize them, i.e. go to a `String`. And then you can just use the formatter, as you already figured out.

---

### RGB to hex string (before OP clarified)

Your are very close. You already managed to convert your RGB values to a hexadecimal string `FF1E00`. To get `0xff1e00` you simply have to add `0x` in front of it and make everything lowercase. Fortunately, both can be done compact with the formatter directly:

```
String.format("0x%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
```

I added `0x` in front of the format and changed your `%...X` template to `%...x` which gives lowercase-hexadecimal integers.

---

Alterntively you can also do easy string manipulation afterwards:

```
hexString = "0x" + hexStrong.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: But that gives a string, not exactly what I need, which is similar to: int hexValue = 0xff1e00

Comment: What do you need then? Please clarify.

Comment: @SirNUB So you want `0xff1e00` as `int` value? I.e. `16719360`?

Comment: @SirNUB I updated my answer based on your comment, is it now correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = 255;
        int g = 30;
        int b = 0;
        String hexString = String.format("%02X%02X%02X", r, g, b);
        int hex = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);
        System.out.println(hex);
        String hexString1 = Integer.toHexString(hex);
        System.out.println(hexString1);
        String hexString2 = String.format("0x%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
        System.out.println(hexString2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
16719360
ff1e00
0xff1e00
```

Comment: Note that the format can do it already without `toLowerCase()`, just `%...x` instead of `%...X`.

Comment: I don't want a hexadecimal string, i need a value.

Comment: @Zabuzard - Thank you. I've incorporated the same.

Comment: @SirNUB - Check the updated answer.